# Why is the output showing as "okNOT OK"? It should have shown "okOK"? Please explain

Tags: c, output

For float value the output is coming"okNOT OK", It should have shown "okOK". But with other datatypes it is working fine. Why is it hapenning?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a=0.5, b=0.7;
    if(a==0.5)
    printf("ok");
    else
    printf("not ok");
    if(b==0.7)
    printf("OK");
    else
    printf("NOT OK");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to perform equality comparisons on floating point values. Use tolerance.

Answer (score 2):

By default, decimal values are `double`, which means you compare `0.7f` (`float`) with `0.7` (`double`). These values are different, as `double` uses more bits to save data about the number itself. To fix your problem, change your if statements to:

```
if(a == 0.5f)
    ...
if(b == 0.7f)
    ...
```

This way you will compare `float a, b` with corresponding `float` values.